Solving non-linear system of equation with R using nleqslv package
I am trying to solve for two variables in two non-linear equations using the 'nleqslv' package in R. I am actually trying to solve for the "shape" parameters of a Beta distribution given its skew and kurtosis. The solution I get does not look right. Have I defined my function correctly?
Given Skew=1.2 and Kurtosis=5, I need Alpha and Beta, the two shape parameters.

Here is my code.
library(nleqslv)

target <- function(x, s=1.2,k=5)
{
  y<-numeric(2)
  alpha<-x[1]
  beta<-x[2]
  y[1]<- 2*(beta-alpha)*sqrt(alpha+beta+1)/((alpha+beta+2)*sqrt(alpha*beta))-s
  y[2] <- (6*((alpha-beta)^2*(alpha+beta+1)-(alpha*beta)*(alpha+beta+2))/((alpha*beta)*(alpha+beta+2)*(alpha+beta+3))-k)
 y
}


# Usage
xstart <- c(1,1)
target(xstart)
nleqslv(xstart, target, control=list(ftol=.0001, allowSingular=TRUE),jacobian=TRUE,method="Newton")


My R output is
> xstart <- c(1,1)
> target(xstart)
[1] -1.2 -6.2
> nleqslv(xstart, target, control=list(ftol=.0001, allowSingular=TRUE),jacobian=TRUE,method="Newton")
$x
[1] 1.227421e+00 8.152425e+05

$fvec
[1]  0.6052255 -0.1117545

I tried to check the solution and I find that y1 and y[2] are not zero (I believe thse are the values in $fvec)
## check solution
s<-1.2
k<-5
alpha<-1.227421e+00
beta<-8.152425e+05

res<-2*(beta-alpha)*sqrt(alpha+beta+1)/((alpha+beta+2)*sqrt(alpha*beta))-s
res
res2<- (6*((alpha-beta)^2*(alpha+beta+1)-(alpha*beta)*(alpha+beta+2))/((alpha*beta)*(alpha+beta+2)*(alpha+beta+3))-k)
res2

> res
[1] 0.6052254
> res2
[1] -0.1117551

I need the values of x1 and x[2] for which the equations y1 and y[2] are both zero.
What should I do to modify my function code?
Thanks for any advice.
